# change function pointer from library A in library B

Tags: c++, matlab, function-pointers, libraries

My situation is the following:

I am writing a toolbox that generates two libraries. The first (A) has all the functions and data-types and can be used in a pure C++ application; the second (B) is an interface to MATLAB.
A pure C++ program would be compiled with

```
g++ $(FLAGS) C.cpp $(MOREFLAGS) -lA
```

while a MATLAB program would be compiled with B linked after A, i.e.

```
mex $(FLAGS) C.cpp $(MOREFLAGS) -lA -lB
```

Now, I would like use a function pointer (`myexit`) to call `std::exit()` for pure C++ applications and `mex_exit()` (which calls `mexErrMsgTxt()`) for MATLAB applications. Following a tutorial on function pointers, I've written something like the snippets below (everything is actually within a namespace, but I have suppressed this for brevity).

```
//A.hpp
#ifndef __A
#define __A
extern void (*myexit)(int);
...
#ifdef mex_h /* defined in mex.h */
#include "B.hpp"
#endif /* mex_h */
#endif /* __A */

//A.cpp
#include "A.hpp"
void (*myexit)(int) = &std::exit;

//B.hpp
#ifndef __B
#define __B
#include <mex.h>
#include "A.hpp"
...
void mex_exit(int);
#endif /* __B */

//B.cpp
#include <mex.h>
#include "A.hpp"
void mex_exit(int err) {mexPrintf("Error code %d\n",err); mexErrMsgTxt("...");}
//void (*myexit)(int) = &mex_exit; // <- I want a line like this to override the line in A.cpp
```

What I have above seems to work for pure C++ code and I find that I can get the right behaviour for MATLAB code if I include the line `myexit = &mex_exit;` in C.cpp, however, I want this behaviour simply from having `#include <mex.h>` and `#include "A.hpp"` in C.cpp and linking to B (i.e. it shouldn't be the user's responsibility to include this line).

Is this possible? If so, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In library B, add a static constructor to set `myexit`:

```
// Consider putting this into a namespace
extern void (*myexit)(int);

// anonymous namespace to avoid name collisions
namespace {
class StaticInit {
  StaticInit() {
    myexit = mex_exit;
  }
} static_init_obj;
}
```

Then link library B to depend on library A:

```
gcc -o libB.so -shared -lA -lmatlab b.o
```

Because libB depends on libA, libA static constructors will be invoked before libB static constructors, so ordering isn't a problem. The `StaticInit` constructor will be invoked during program startup (before `main()`), and set `myexit` for you.

Comment: Actually, there is one small problem... when I enable optimisation (`mex -O` as opposed to `mex -g`, which passes `-O2 -DNDEBUG` to g++), then it appears that `static_init_obj` is optimised away unless I put something like `mexPrintf("Overriding exit function for MATLAB\n");` in the constructor, but this causes a fair amount of noise at the MATLAB prompt the first time a MEX file is loaded into MATLAB. Is there a better way to prevent static_init_obj from being optimised away?

Comment: @Brett, this is a bug in your compiler; however, you could try calling a no-op function located in a different .cpp file

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the GCC [`constructor` function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to a function in `B.cpp`, which overwrites the value of `myexit`.

Not portable, of course.

Comment: You can do this more portably by creating a class with a constructor that does the initialization, then creating a static instance of the class. The `constructor` attribute is only really needed for C.

Comment: @bdonlan: That's a good point.  I hadn't registered that this was C++!

Comment: @bdonlan: Actually, hang on.  Can we guarantee that the static constructor will be invoked *after* `myexit` is initialised?

Comment: If the library or executable containing the static constructor declares a dependency on the library with `myexit`, then yes. Incidentally, the same ordering issues apply with the function attribute as well.

Comment: @bdonian: Mind if I write out your idea as a complete answer, with example code?

Comment: @bdonlan: Are you saying there's a way to avoid the static initialization order fiasco?

Comment: @Oli, if the objects are in different libraries, yes.

Comment: @Oli, also note that on Linux, initialized static POD types are placed directly in the data segment, and therefore initialized before _any_ static constructors are run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's  possible to do what you're asking (portably, that is). Perhaps the best you can do is provide an `init` function in B that sets everything up for "Matlab mode", including changing the `myexit` function pointer. That way, the user is not aware of implementation details. The advantage with this approach is if later you need to add more initialization code, you can add it inside the `init` function without breaking the client's code.

I think it's a bad idea for a function pointer to be part of a library's API. You should provide a `myexit` function that invokes the function pointer on behalf of the user:

```
void myexit(int err) {myexit_fn_ptr(err);}
```

While you're at it, provide a cleanup function as part of your library API. This function is the counterpart to `init` and must be called by the client before the program exits so that the library may perform cleanup. Even if you currently don't have cleanup work to do, add an empty cleanup function to your API anyway so that you have a placeholder for the future.